# FFmpeg opening key info file - could not write header for output file

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I want muxer mp4 to m3u8 with key.
I can do this when I put all files in same directory.

- File 480.mp4.key
- File video 480.mp4
- File hls info have name: "480.mp4.keyinfo"

When I run the command `ffmpeg -i 480.mp4 -hls_time 10 -hls_key_info_file 480.mp4.keyinfo output.mp4.m3u8`
everything runs normally.

However, I meet a problem when I move file "480.mp4.key" and file "480.mp4.keyinfo" into another directory such as `/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/keys/auto_scan/testhh/2/123/480.mp4.keyinfo`
I also change key directory in file keyinfo

After that I run

```
ffmpeg -i 480.mp4 -hls_time 10 -hls_key_info_file 480.mp4.keyinfo output.mp4.m3u8 ffmpeg -i output/testhh/2/123/480.mp4 -hls_time 10 -hls_key_info_file /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/keys/auto_scan/testhh/2/123/480.mp4.keyinfo output/testhh/2/123/480.mp4.m3u8
```

But I get an error:

```
 error opening key info file /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/keys/auto_scan//testhh/2/123/output/testhh/2/123/480.mp4.keyinfo
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue..did you find a fix for this?

Comment: so do i ... i can't fix it

Answer (score 0):

use `.txt` extension

for example

```
-hls_key_info_file key_info.txt
```